# VSTO word add-in get docx as byte array

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I’m writing a plugin for word and would like to get the docx files as a byte array and send it to a web service.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx):

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Not really, Can i use that from a word addin, using ActiveDocument?